# MS-Access: Merge two tables "below" each other

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have two tables in my Access-database. They look something like this:

```
Table1
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Kabelnummer  |  Column1 |  Column2 |  Column3 |         
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 2            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 3            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 4            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+

table2
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Kabelnummer  |  Column1 |  Column2 |  Column3 |        
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 2            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 3            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 4            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I need a query that gives me 1 table with the data from table1 added to the data from table2:

```
TableTotal
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Kabelnummer  |  Column1 |  Column2 |  Column3 | 
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 2            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 3            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 4            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 2            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 3            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 4            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

The names "Column1", "Column2" and "Column3" are the same in both tables

Comment: Neither answer here guarantees any order to the output rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM  Table1

UNION

SELECT *
FROM table2;
```

Answer (score 2):

The question asks for non-distinct values while the current answers provide distinct values. The method below provides non-distinct values such that

```
SELECT *
FROM  Table1

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM table2;
```

which is often more efficient than the union method, particularly with large data sets (not having to compute the distinct).

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to **append the second table to the first one**, it can be achieved this way

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 SELECT * FROM TABLE2;
```

The caveat with these other queries is that yes, they do the job, but create ***a third table*** with the joined data.