# SQL Server: efficient way to combine two columns to distinct values?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sqlperformance

This is a performance question where I want to combine two columns from two separate tables. How can you do the combination?

I understand this as `or` condition such that

```
SELECT a.contract1 or b.contract2 from TABLE1 a, TABLE2 b
```

where my goal is to get a single column where each element is either in Contract1 of Table1 or Contract2 of Table2. The `or` notation does not differentiate between distinct values and other values. I need distinct values. The proposed solution, the union method, acts slow with large datasets over many GBs because of the underlying distinct.

Please propose efficient methods to deal with the performance.

**Input**

> **Column in Table A**
>
> ```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> ```
>
> **Golumn in Table B**
>
> ```
> 1
> 3
> 5
> ```

**Wanted Output**

```
1
2
3
5
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [merge two tables "below" eachother](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923643/merge-two-tables-below-eachother)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's what `UNION` does

```
SELECT contract1 FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT contract2 FROM TABLE2
```

**Edit**

The performance problem you're talking about in your comment is probably caused by the nature of `UNION` itself; what happens behind the scenes is that the dbms executes both the statements separately then applies a `distinct` on the resulting set. On large tables this latter step may cause problems with the overall performances, and you can confirm that by switching to `UNION ALL` (which won't perform the `distinct`).

If you cannot settle for `UNION ALL`, because you don't want duplicates, I found [this interesting article](https://blog.falafel.com/t-sql-tip-avoid-union/) that proposes a solution for this kind of issues. It involves the usage of a table variable, that you populate with your two statements and from where you select to get the final result.

Essentially the steps are

```
DECLARE @Result TABLE (
  Contract varchar(50)
  — Example of how to declare a PK within a table variable
  PRIMARY KEY ( Contract )
)

INSERT @Result
SELECT Contract1
FROM Table1

INSERT @Result
SELECT Contract2
FROM Table2

SELECT *
FROM @Result
```

but you can find a more detailed explaination at the link above

Comment: @hhh Note: `Union all` would not execute a distinct so 1 and 3 would be repeated.  Sometimes you want this.  Since you didn't know about union I wanted to ensure you knew about union all.